# drupal-----where are these variable declared?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module

i saw some module using eg:

```
   function statistics_exit() {
     global $user, $recent_activity;
     .......
      }
```

where are these variables($user, $recent_activity) declared? thank you. how should i know the values of there variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$user is a global var which represents the current logged in user.

for more info about the Drupal core globals visit http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/6

Answer (score 2):

The global $user object is first set in the [sess_read()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--session.inc/function/sess_read/6) function in session.inc. I don't know where $recent_activity is set. If you want to know the value, you can simply print the variable like this:

```
<?php
  global $user, $recent_activity;
  var_dump($user, $recent_activity);
?>
```

Or if you have devel module installed:

```
<?php
  global $user, $recent_activity;
  dsm($user);
  dsm($recent_activity);
?>
```